# MySQL equivalent to perform UPDATE SET FROM / MERGE INTO

Tags: mysql, merge, sql-update

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE `vendor_contacts` (
  `vendor_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name_initials` varchar(45),
  PRIMARY KEY (`vendor_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

With the following insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO `vendor_contacts`
    VALUES (5,'Davison','Michelle',''),
           (12,'Mayteh','Kendall',''),
           (17,'Onandonga','Bruce',''),
           (44,'Antavius','Anthony',''),
           (76,'Bradlee','Danny',''),
           (94,'Suscipe','Reynaldo',''),
           (101,'O\'Sullivan','Geraldine',''),
           (123,'Bucket','Charles','');
```

I am trying to assign the the column, name_initials with the following command, derived from a PostgreSQL [Update>Set>From]:

```
UPDATE vendor_contacts
SET name_initials = t.initials
FROM (
        SELECT vendor_id, last_name, first_name,
            CONCAT(LEFT(first_name, 1), LEFT(last_name, 1)) as initials
        FROM vendor_contacts;
) t 
WHERE vendor_id = t.vendor_id;
```

Since that didn't work I tried the Oracle SQL Merge Into:

```
MERGE INTO vendor_contacts
USING (
        SELECT vendor_id, last_name, first_name,
            CONCAT(LEFT(first_name, 1), LEFT(last_name, 1)) as initials
        FROM vendor_contacts;
      ) t
ON (vendor_id = t.vendor_id)
WHEN matched THEN
    UPDATE SET name_initials = t.initials;
```

MERGE didn't work.

I tried a subquery, which did not work as well:

```
UPDATE vendor_contacts vc
SET name_initials = (SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(first_name, 1), LEFT(last_name, 1))
                     FROM vendor_contacts vcsq
                     WHERE vcsq.vendor_id = vc.vendor_id);
```

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `UPDATE`? I don't see you inserting anything.

Comment: Was there a *question*?  Describing the observed behavior as "*didn't work*" is imprecise, and practically useless in diagnosing the issue. If the description of the behavior was more precise e.g. MySQL returned Error 1093  "can't reference target table 'vendor_contacts' for update in FROM clause" ... that's a more specific problem, with some specific workarounds. And since MySQL doesn't support the `MERGE` statement, we might surmise that MySQL returned error 1046 "an error in your SQL syntax". Why the rigmarole? Why not just a straight single table update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why all these complications, why not just?

```
UPDATE vendor_contacts 
SET name_initials = CONCAT(LEFT(first_name, 1), LEFT(last_name, 1));
```

It sets the initials field based the values of the other columns.

But even this query is something that you shouldn't be running. The right thing to do is to drop the `name_initials` column. You don't need it. Because it's the result of a simple calculation and generally one does not create a column for a simple calculation. You can either use a generated column, or simple.

```
SELECT *, 
CONCAT(LEFT(first_name, 1), LEFT(last_name, 1)) AS name_initials FROM vendor_contacts;
```